# mfc combobox button complex control: Lbutton down event is not fired for the first click of button

Tags: combobox, mfc, listbox

i am creating a complex control with one combobox and one button in mfc.The combobox has styles "CBS_DROPDOWNLIST | CBS_HASSTRINGS | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_VSCROLL" and it is editable combobox.I am using COleControl class as a parent for these two.

When the dropdown is open if i click on the button for first time the dropdown is closed and no lbutton down event is generated for the button.If i click the button for second time the lbutton down event is generated.The problem here is i need the lbutton event to be generated for the first time.

Please somebody help me out.Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

That's just how Windows controls work. When a combobox is open and you click somewhere outside of it, it closes, and the click is ignored.

What you can do if you really want to do what you describe (although you shouldn't, and it's hairy to do, there are many edge cases over this general idea you will have to solve!):

- subclass combo box
- catch lbuttondown
- call default handler from your derived class
- then repost message to global queue with corrected coordinates (with ::SendInput)

Comment: I suspect that the droplist part of the combo grabs all mouse input using `WM_SETCAPTURE` when it is visible so that it can detect mouse clicks outside of itself.

Answer (score 0):

First, you do not receive any events, since Windows controls, receive/generate messages, not events.
There is no such message as WM_SETCAPTURE.

When the left mouse button is clicked on the combo in drop button area, combo calls shows a drop list box and SetCapture is called to set capture on drop box window. 
Any consecutive mouse left button down message is received by the drop list box regardless of cursor position.

Drop box is hidden, mouse capture released and combo receives command message with CBN_CLOSEUP notification code and another command message with CBN_SELCHANGE code if selection was cjanged.
As you can see the click is not ignored, it is consumed by the drop list box.

If you want to carry on the mouse click to your button or any other control in a dialog or custom control, you have to do some additional coding.

I have attaches sample app that demonstrate my approach.

Some things you have to do that are demonstrated in the sample:

Subclass combo box (use wizard to add variable of the CComboBox type).

Derive class from CListBox (CDropListBox).

Get combo box info in OnInitDialog and subclass drop list box.

```
    COMBOBOXINFO cmbi = { sizeof(COMBOBOXINFO) };

    m_Combo.GetComboBoxInfo(&cmbi);

    m_DropListBox.SubclassWindow(cmbi.hwndList);
```

Add handler for WM_LBUTTONDOWN message and add the code as in the sample.

Now, each time drop list box is dismissed when you call the base class, WM_LBUTTONDOWN message will be relayed to any control that is under the cursor at the moment WM_LBUTTONDOWN message was generated.

[Sample download](https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=ffd6a5dd12ebeeb0&id=FFD6A5DD12EBEEB0!278)